# Filtering Google search results to find indexed links with just the HTTP or HTTPS protocol

Tags: google-search, search-results

I'm moving some sites from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. Most of these have 100's of pages indexed. Is there a way to find out which pages in Google's index are still on `HTTP`, e.g. through Google search operators? (Or which pages are already on `HTTPS`?)

`-http` or `-https` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

While writing out this question I found the answer: `inurl:` does the trick.

To see all `HTTPS` results:

```
site:example.com inurl:https
```

To see all `HTTP` results:

```
site:example.com inurl:http
```

To verify, this one gives 0 results: `site:example.com inurl:http inurl:https`.